# How to give data dynamically in a dialog box using visual c++

Tags: visual-c++

How can I send data to a dialog box dynamically?

In a previous project I used edit boxes (e.g for 3 conductors) and gave those data separately for each conductor. Now I have to give them dynamically and I don't have standard number of conductors and I can't use edit box again.

Could you please give me an idea or a good link describing step by step how to create a table in a dialog box dynamically?
I have created a dialog box in which I insert data about conductors (resistivity, permeability, diameter etc (electric power systems Smile | :) )) in edit boxes but I have done it only for 3 conductors. I have to insert-edit the number of conductors and then edit their characteristics. But I can't use again edit boxes because this is static. I want something like a dynamic table which will have rows=number of conductors and columns about is characteristic (resistivity, permeability, diameter)and edit them in dialog box. I don't know how to upload my executable to male clear what I have done but here is a part of my code for the static case of three conductors Smile | :) I want another dynamic way to edit data :/

```
void CInputView::OnLinefeaturesFeatures()
{
    // TODO: Add your command handler code here
    CInputDoc* pDoc = GetDocument();
    CFeaturesDialog DialogWindow;
    DialogWindow.m_DialogCon = m_NumCond;
    DialogWindow.m_DialogLayers = m_Layers;
    DialogWindow.m_DialogPermeability = m_AirPermeability;
    DialogWindow.m_DialogAirConductivity = m_AirConductivity;
    DialogWindow.m_DialogAirPermittivity = m_AirPermittivity;
    DialogWindow.m_DialogEarthPermeability1 = m_EarthPermeability1;
    DialogWindow.m_DialogEarthConductivity1 = m_EarthConductivity1;
    DialogWindow.m_DialogEarthPermittivity1 = m_EarthPermittivity;
    DialogWindow.m_DialogDepth = m_depth;
    DialogWindow.m_DialogEarthPermeability2 = m_EarthPermeability2;
    DialogWindow.m_DialogEarthConductivity2 = m_EarthConductivity2;
    DialogWindow.m_DialogEarthPermittivity2 = m_EarthPermittivity2;
    DialogWindow.m_Dialogfrequency = m_frequency;
    if (DialogWindow.DoModal() == IDOK)
    {
        m_NumCond = DialogWindow.m_DialogCon;
        m_Layers = DialogWindow.m_DialogLayers;
        m_AirPermeability = DialogWindow.m_DialogPermeability;
        m_AirConductivity = DialogWindow.m_DialogAirConductivity;
        m_AirPermittivity = DialogWindow.m_DialogAirPermittivity;
        m_EarthPermeability1 = DialogWindow.m_DialogEarthPermeability1;
        m_EarthConductivity1 = DialogWindow.m_DialogEarthConductivity1;
        m_EarthPermittivity = DialogWindow.m_DialogEarthPermittivity1;
        m_depth = DialogWindow.m_DialogDepth;
        m_EarthPermeability2 = DialogWindow.m_DialogEarthPermeability2;
        m_EarthConductivity2 = DialogWindow.m_DialogEarthConductivity2;
        m_EarthPermittivity2 = DialogWindow.m_DialogEarthPermittivity2;
        m_frequency = DialogWindow.m_Dialogfrequency;
    }



}
```

Comment: can you post some code you have so far as starting point

Comment: If you only need to edit first column use a `CListCtrl` or a `CMFCListCtrl`. If you need to edit everywhere I can suggest the use of 3rd party *Ultimate Grid*